# Is there a presentationclose option like in excel?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Hwello,

I have a routine in excel located in the ThisWorkbook module which detects the "save" or "close" event and performs some commands before the "save" or "close" is executed.

Is there something similar in Powerpoint?

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.presentationclose for an application-level event.

Comment: Yes, it is, but not so simple/available as in Excel... You need a class, an initializer `Sub` and a way to call it when the presentation starts (usually, to write a specific `Sub` called  by Ribbon `OnLoad` event) . Since no event is available without the respective class, Open event is not available, too. If nobody will answer your question until I will be at home, I can try answering it after some hours.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a class able to trigger PowerPoint events. So, please insert a class module in the project, name it "clsPPEvents" and paste the next code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_PresentationClose(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
  MsgBox "Presentation """ & Pres.Name & """ is closing..."
  'do here whatever you need to do before presentation closing...
End Sub
```

2. Please, copy the next code in a standard module. It will initialize the above class to trigger events of the PowerPoint Application:

```
Option Explicit

Public myApp As New clsPPEvents

Sub EnableEvents()
   Set myApp.App = Application
End Sub
```

3. `EnableEvents` Sub must be called when your presentation is opening. Since, PowerPoint events are not enabled at that time, you need to find a way to call it in order to initialize the class. It can be done from an Add-in, which is a little more complicated, or using a Ribbon event (`OnLoad`) (triggered when the needed presentation is open). I will show you this second way.

3.1 Copy the next code in a standard module (the same you used before, or another one):

```
Public Sub onLoadRibbon(myRibbon As IRibbonUI)
  Debug.Print "Ribbon Loaded" 'just to see that it has been called
  EnableEvents 'initialize the events class
End Sub
```

Save the presentation and close it.

3.2  The above code must be called by Ribbon during loading time. So, you need to download 'Office RibbonX editor' (from [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/officecustomuieditorfiles.zip). Download the zip archive, extract its content in a specific folder and run `CustomUIEditor.exe`. To learn how to use it, look to the [next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scXOixpWX6M) video. It shows how to be used in Excel ribbon, but it must be used exactly in the same way for PowerPoint.
The above code must be called by Ribbon during loading time. So, you need to download 'Office RibbonX editor' (from [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/officecustomuieditorfiles.zip). Download the zip archive, extract its content in a specific folder and run `CustomUIEditor.exe`. To learn how to use it, look to the [next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scXOixpWX6M) video. It shows how to be used in Excel ribbon, but it must be used exactly in the same way for PowerPoint.

Use it and copy the next XML code, in inserted `customUI14.xml` (for Office 2010 or more recent than it):

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
onLoad="onLoadRibbon" ></customUI>
```

Or the next one in `customUI.xml` for Office 2007:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
onLoad="onLoadRibbon" ></customUI>
```

Inserting both `custom UI` the presentation will work as it should in all Office versions greater than 2007, inclusively.

Press `Validate` to check if the XML code is correct and if it is, press `Save` button.

4. Now, open the presentation, do whatever you need with it, then try closing it. `App_PresentationClose` event will be triggered and you will receive the message `"Presentation " & Presentation Name & " is closing..."`

Please, send some feedback after testing the suggested solution.

If something is not clear enough, do not hesitate to specifically ask for clarifications